# How to create a Java 2D array with 1s and 0s?

Tags: java, arrays

The printed result should be like this (I don't know how to format it, but imagine a 9x9 2d array where the 1's create an X):

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
int [][] myArray = new int[9][1]; 
    
for (int row = 0 ; row < 9 ; row++)
    for (int column = 0 ; column < 1 ; column++)
        myArray[row][column]= 0;
```

How would I create a while loop for this?

Comment: "`int [][] myArray = new int[9][1];`" what do you think that does, bearing in mind you apparently want a 9x9 array.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
public class Main
{
static int SIZE = 9;

 public static void main(String []args){
    int[][] arr = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        arr[i][i] = 1;
        arr[i][SIZE-1-i] = 1;
    }
    printArr(arr);
 }
 
 public static void printArr(int[][] arr){
     for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       {
          for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
          {
             System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
       }
    }

}
```

I have added a print method so you will see the desired result.
few points about the above code:

1. there is no need to set all values to 0. this is by default.
2. so the only thing that left to do is to set the diagonals to 1's. that can be done in 1 for loop as suggested above. the first line in the loop creates the diagonal from top left to bottom right. the second line creates the other diagonal
3. you can change SIZE variable to any size that you want, I set it to 9, but it can be any int.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if column-row==0 or column+row==8. With the first check you get the cross from the left top corner to the bottom right, with the second check the cross from the top right corner to the bottom left.

As mentioned in a comment you also need to initialize your array with [9][9] and change the upper bound check in the second array to 9 as well.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int [][] myArray = new int[9][9]; 
    
    for (int row = 0 ; row < 9 ; row++) {
        for (int column = 0 ; column < 9 ; column++){
            myArray[row][column]= 0; 
            if (column-row==0 || column+row==8){
                myArray[row][column]= 1; 
            }
            System.out.print(myArray[row][column]);
        }
      System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
```